# i want to do a sum between 2 numbers, if the number is above 20 the program will add 8 and if it is under 20 it takes off 5. i cant find my errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors, sum

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, result, result2, result3;

    printf("Primeiro numero: \n", num1);
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Segundo numero: \n", num2);
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    result = num1 + num2;

    if (result > 20) {

        result2 = result + 8;

        printf("Resultado: %d \n", result2);
        scanf("%d", &result2);
    }

    else {
        (result < 20);

        result3 = result - 5;

        printf("Resultado: %d \n", result3);
        scanf("%d", &result3);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What's the problem, where's the error, what is the error?

Comment: What do you expect the line `printf("Primeiro numero: \n", num1);` to be doing?

Comment: What is the purpose of `scanf("%d", &result2);` and `scanf("%d", &result3);`

Comment: Tagging C++ for an obvious C program could be an issue.

Comment: There's no reason to do `scanf("%d", &result2);`. You've already scanned `num1` and `num2` and are using those values to compute `result2`. You shouldn't be reading the value of `result2` from user input.

Comment: What does `else { (result < 20);` do, in your mind?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What input do you use, what output or behavior do you get and what output/behavior do you expect. You should enable compiler warnings and fix the warnings. If you get any errors, copy&paste the exact error messages to your question and format them as a code block.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the `scanf` from your `if/else` statements.
your `else` statement has `(result < 20);` which does nothing. So you have remove it too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()

{
    
    int num1, num2, result;
    printf("Primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("Segundo numero: \n");
    scanf("%d" , &num2);
    
    result = num1 + num2;
    
    
    if (result > 20) {    
        printf("Resultado: %d \n", result + 8);
    }
    else {
        printf("Resultado: %d \n", result - 5);
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in your code:

> `printf("Primeiro numero: \n", num1);`

`num1` is not used by `printf` there; you need a `%d` in the format string (the first argument) to indicate you want to print a number (the second argument in this case). If it were used, you could get any output because `num1` is not initialized yet; you are reading it in the next line of code with a `scanf`. So just print a message telling the user to enter a number, then read that number, then print it.

> `(result < 20);`

That check should go together with the `else`. So you first check `result > 20`, and then, if that is not true, you go on and check `result < 20`. Notice you are not checking `result == 20`.

> `scanf("%d", &result2);`
> `scanf("%d", &result3);`

Those 2 lines are not needed. You just want to print some results, not read them from the user.

Also:

- Prefer to declare variables as near as possible to the place you are first going to use them.
- Try and initialize variables when you declare them.
- You don't really need to declare `result2` and `result3`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/WW9dG3dcb)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    
    printf("Primeiro numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("%d\n", num1);
    printf("Segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("%d\n", num2);
    
    int result = num1 + num2;

    if (result > 20) {
        printf("Resultado: %d\n", result + 8);
    }
    else if (result < 20) {
        printf("Resultado: %d\n", result - 5);
    }
}
```